# Compressing a bitmap in memory with C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, compression, zlib, image-compression

I have a program that grabs an image using BitBlt() and is stored in a variable `unsigned char* image`. Ideally before uploading it to my server I would like to compress it since it's somewhat large uncompressed. I've tried a couple different ways with zlib, writing my own run length encoding method, and more but no luck. I chalk it up to me not having a strong understanding compression.

I searched and found some examples using zlib but my image appears to stay the same size after attempting to compress it. Here is that code:

```
unsigned char* compressBitmap(size_t inImgSize, unsigned char* inImage)
{
    uLongf srcLen = inImgSize;
    uLongf destLen = compressBound(srcLen);
    unsigned char* outImage = new unsigned char[destLen];

    int res = compress((Bytef*)outImage, &destLen, (Bytef*)inImage, srcLen);
    return outImage;
}
```

I checked and confirmed it is not returning an error. Everything is executed and the image makes it to the server fine, just not compressed at all. I am probably making a bunch of dumb mistakes so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be ingoring the `destLen`, and you just return a plain pointer to a buffer without a corresponding size. After `compress` completes, it holds the **actual** size of the compressed data in the buffer (likely less than the worst-case given by `compressBound`). | Given that you're in C++, it might be a good idea to use something like `std::vector` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Also, ZLib is a reasonable choice (after all, that's what PNG is based on), but since you're dealing with an image, you might as well use an image codec directly, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lossless compression on image data doesn't usually lend itself to reduced file sizes (especially photos, simple icons maybe). If you want to know whether the compression is actually working, try uploading an entirely black image and see if the size reduces. If you can see a reduction in file size on a black image, but not the images you are using, you may have to consider using a lossy format instead (e.g. jpeg, png, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried an entirely black image but same size. I am OK with using one of those other formats. My problem was I couldn't find a library or way to keep it all in memory. Libraries like boost seem to want to write out and/or read in a file. Do you have a recommendation for converting it but sticking it in memory directly?

Comment: PNG is a lossless image codec. It compresses using ZLib. There are many others that are either purely lossless, or support that mode.